# sendmail authentication issue with special character

Tags: linux, ubuntu, smtp, sendmail, nagios

I am trying to use sendmail with nagios for mail notifications.
I have config file /etc/mail/auth and a hash copy auth.db. The configuration is working fine with credentials that doesn't have a special character in the password field. Example:

> AuthInfo:smtp.mymail.com "U:Example" "I:example@mymail.com"
>   "P:NoSpecialCharacter123"

But my mail have a special character in the password:

> AuthInfo:smtp.mymail.com "U:Example2" "I:example2@mymail.com"
>   "P:SpecialCharacter%123"

And i am receiving

> Feb  7 09:27:42 localhost sm-mta[10204]: 0179A0Gn008954:
>   to=, ctladdr= (0/0),
>   delay=00:17:42, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=300387,
>   relay=mymail.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by
>   mymail.

The logs from mymail server are that the password is incorrect.

Does sendmail support passwords with special characters?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you try to add it in single quotes? `'P:SpecialCharacter%123'`

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail mail lookups treat `%0`, `%1`, `%2` … in value in a special way. Such string may be exapanded/replaced  e.g. `%0` is replayed by key looked up.

If you want to get `%` after lookup put `%%` in the value.

```
# KEY SPACES VALUE
KEY VALUE
```